# ReferenceError: Routes is not defined Discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
client.once("ready", () =>{
    console.log("Bot is online");
    
    const CLIENT_ID = client.user.id;

    const rest = new REST({
        version: "9"
    }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

    (async () => {
        try {
          if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
            await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), {
              body: commands
            });
            console.log("sucessfully resgistered (/) commamds globally");
          } else {
            await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID), {
              body: commands
            });
            console.log("sucessfully resgistered (/) commands locally");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        }
    })();
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if (!command) return;

    try{
        // await command.execute(interaction);
        throw new Error("Command not implemented.");
    } catch(err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);

        await interaction.reply({
            content: "An error occurred while executing that command.",
            emphemeral:true
        })
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

**Error:**

```
ReferenceError: Routes is not defined
    at C:\DiscordBot\index.js:43:28
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\DiscordBot\index.js:51:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:367:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:189:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:475:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:447:16)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your code and install it if needed.

```js
const {
    Routes,
} = require('discord-api-types/v9');
```

You specified Routes here but it is defined:

```js
await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), {
```

```js
await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID), {
```